# update a position field by reordering a table

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I am trying to reorder a table.
This table contains a list of attributes for a product. I want to reorder all the "color" attributes (`id_attribute_group` = 2) in an alphabetical order (except white and black coming first). This query gives me the result I want :

```
SELECT a.`id_attribute`, a.`id_attribute_group`, a.`color`, (@count := @count + 1) AS position
FROM `ps_attribute_lang` al, `ps_attribute` a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) tcount 
WHERE a.`id_attribute` = al.`id_attribute`
AND a.`id_attribute_group` = 2
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN  al.`name` LIKE '% - white' THEN 1
    WHEN al.`name` LIKE '% - black' THEN 2
    ELSE SUBSTRING(al.`name`, LOCATE(' - ', al.`name`)+3) #prefix for color
END 
ASC
```

Produces something like

```
+==============+====================+=========+==========+
| id_attribute | id_attribute_group | color   | position |
+==============+====================+=========+==========+
| 12           | 2                  | #FFFFFF | 1        | // WHITE
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 45           | 2                  | #FEFEFE | 2        | // WHITE
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 25           | 2                  | #000000 | 3        | // BLACK
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 1112         | 2                  | #010101 | 4        | // BLACK
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 120          | 2                  | #57585C | 5        | // ANTHRACITE
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| ...          | ...                | ...     | ...      | // ANTHRACITE
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 6            | 2                  | #4D5166 | 1150     | // ZINC
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
```

Great ! Now I just want to `REPLACE` the entries :

```
REPLACE INTO `ps_attribute` 
[the previous query]
```

And now it orders everything by id but does change the position :

```
+==============+====================+=========+==========+
| id_attribute | id_attribute_group | color   | position |
+==============+====================+=========+==========+
| 1            | 2                  | #ab4894 | 1        | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 2            | 2                  | #ba4158 | 2        | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 3            | 2                  | #016873 | 3        | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 4            | 2                  | #894657 | 4        | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 5            | 2                  | #fa4891 | 5        | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| ...          | ...                | ...     | ...      | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
| 1150         | 2                  | #4894af | 1150     | 
+--------------+--------------------+---------+----------+
```

What I am missing ? I also tried to make a `TEMPORARY` table, but it does not work either. If I display it with

```
SELECT * FROM `temp` ORDER BY `position`
```

I get the same result as above. I also tried to use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you just can `ALTER` the table:

```
ALTER TABLE
    ps_attribute_lang as al
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN  al.`name` LIKE '% - white' THEN 1
    WHEN al.`name` LIKE '% - black' THEN 2
    ELSE SUBSTRING(al.`name`, LOCATE(' - ', al.`name`)+3) #prefix for color
END 
ASC
```

**EDIT**

Try to do the re-numbering this way:

```
    SELECT result.*, (@count := @count + 1) AS position
FROM
(SELECT a.`id_attribute`, a.`id_attribute_group`, a.`color`, al.`name`
FROM `ps_attribute_lang` al, `ps_attribute` a
WHERE a.`id_attribute` = al.`id_attribute`
AND a.`id_attribute_group` = 2
AND al.`id_lang` = 1
ORDER BY
CASE
    WHEN  al.`name` LIKE '% - white' THEN 1
    WHEN al.`name` LIKE '% - black' THEN 2
    ELSE SUBSTRING(al.`name`, LOCATE(' - ', al.`name`)+3) #prefix for color
END 
ASC) as result
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 0) tcount
```

Comment: I'm not a god in sql, but I can't see how this could update the `position` field, and I thought `ALTER TABLE` was used to change its architecture

Comment: Do you want to reorder your original table (which?) or generate a new one with the new order?

Comment: Reorder the original `ps_attribute` table (`ps_attribute_lang` is just here for the actual color name)

Comment: I spent a couple of hours just for a single tiny thing... This drove me mad. Anyway, `ALTER TABLE table AS t` gives me syntax error

Comment: Can you provide a sqlfiddle or some example data (CREATE-Statements)? Its hard to look for a solution in such a complex query without data...

Comment: There is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5871/4)... I don't get it. It works well here with `AND al.id_lang = 1` but if I remove it, the position is wrong. Yet, on my local server, the position is still good without it...

Comment: Great, I didn't even thought of externalizing the counter. It now always works. I guess it was doing strange things for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing a `WHERE` condition :

```
AND al.`id_lang` = 1
```

Now the query with `REPLACE INTO` works just fine. But I still does not understand why this didn't work without this condition !